# How to add common dependencies using Gradle custom Plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to write one custom Gradle plugin and intent is we have good number of microservice.
Those microservices use lots of common library. So instead of declaring those library in each sub-project.
I want to create one custom Gradle plugin where I will add all library and other project just need to use that plugin.
I am done with custom plugin and its integration with other project and looks fine.

But not sure how to add common dependencies in plugin. either implementing Plugin interface or something else.

In my plugin class I am trying to the following things and its not working.

Can someone suggest me how can achieve this task. is it something I need to change here or need to follow some different approach.

```
public class CommonResourcesPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        log.info("Applying depdencies ");
        project.getDependencies().add("implementation", "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web");
        project.getDependencies().add("implementation", "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "its not working"? Is there any error? Your code looks fine, it should work beside the missing version in the dependencies, but I guess you are using some BOM. Maybe you need to add the BOM as part of your plugin.

Comment: I think I have something similar but all custom plugin is in its own project, the dependencies are in that project's build.gradle and then all the other projects include the project that contains the custom plugin.